# Related posts by taxonomies does not work , what could be the reason?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

everybody. Related posts by taxonomies does not work , what could be the reason?

```
$tax_IDs = array();
foreach ($tags as $tag) {
    $tax_IDs[] = $tag->ID;
}

$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'films',
  'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),
  'showposts'=> 3,
  'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'actors',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => $tax_IDs
        )
    )
);
 $my_query = new wp_query($args);
 if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {

 echo '<div class="related-slider">';
        while ($my_query->have_posts()) {
            $my_query->the_post();
        ?>
            <div><?php the_title(); ?></div>       
        <?php
        }
        echo '</div>';
    }
 wp_reset_query();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your tax_query is using an invalid `field` type. Try:

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'films',
  'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),
  'showposts'=> 3,
  'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'actors',
            'field' => 'term_id',
            'terms' => $tax_IDs
        )
    )
);
```

See the [Taxonomy Parameters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters) of WP_Query for more options if that doesn't wok.

Comment: updated settings, content is not displayed, what else could be the reason ?

Comment: Do you know for sure your array of $tax_IDs is passing in correct information?